# Writing content to a new empty tab in Chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to open a new empty tab and add some HTML (or anything else) to it.

I am successful in opening a new empty tab, but not in adding anything to it.

Here is the code in file "background.js":

```
chrome.tabs.create({url:"about:blank"}, function(tab){chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code: "document.write('Some HTML tags')"});
});
```

Usually, you open a new tab to an existing URL, and you ask for permission in the manifest file, e.g.

```
"permissions" : ["tabs","http://*/*","https://*/*"]
```

but I am not sure what permissions to ask for an empty tab, if any.

Comment: `about:blank` doesn't match pattern "http://*/*","https://*/*". It has protocol `about:` at least.

Comment: Have you tried writing directly in the URL, like `chrome.tabs.create({url:'javascript:document.write("<h1>Hello, World!</h1>")'});` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `javascript:` URL to write your content. For example:

```
chrome.tabs.create({url:'javascript:document.write("<h1>Hello, World!</h1>")'});
```